# Cesium 3D Map help

Tags: convert, 3d, 3d-map, cesium

I am new to cesium and I want to display 3d shapefile using cesium.Conversion of shapefile in czml and display into cesium in main hurdle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, First convert shapefile to geojson, then use GeoJsonDataSource to add the geojson to the scene.
Like this [Cesium Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=Showcases).